# how to get an id token and access token after call to "loginredirect" in msal

Tags: access-token, azure-ad-msal

hello i look for way to retrieve id token and find access token after i call to
this.authService.loginRedirect({scopes: [    'user.read',
'openid',
'profile',
'user_impersonation']}); in msal
I look in previous post but didn't find an answer for it so ill apricate any help
best regards ,
gal

Answer (score -2):

find my answer with localStorage.getItem('msal.idtoken')